# Python Script invalid syntax answer

Tags: python

This is a python script i am working on, i am new to pyhton scripting, this is what we are learning in school, i need some help with it. this is the error i keep getting, i dont understand what the invalid syntax is. thank you for any help. The "import maya.cmds as cmds", this is part of the program i am working on,

```
        #Error: line 1: invalid syntax
        #   File "<maya console>", line 27
        #     transformInScene = cmds.ls(type='transform')
        #                    ^
        # SyntaxError: invalid syntax #
```

cmds.file(new=True,force=True)

```
        import maya.cmds as cmds
        def changeXtransformValue(myList, percentage=1.0):
            """
            Changes the value of each transform in the scene by a percentange.
            Parameters:
            percentage - Percentange to change each transform's value. Default value is 1.
            Returns:
            Nothing.
            """
            *# The ls command is the list command. It is used to list various nodes
            # in the current scene. You can also use it to list selected nodes.*
            transformInScene = cmds.ls(type='transform')
            found = False
            for thisTransform in transformInScene:
                if i not in ['front','persp','side','top']:
                    found = True
                    break
                else:
                    found = False
            if found == False:
                   sphere1 = cmds.polySphere()[0]
                   cmds.xform(sphere1, t = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
*#This is the line where I am having problems*
            transformInScene = cmds.ls(type='transform')
            sel =cmds.ls(sl=True)
            if sel :
                transformInScene = sel
            # If there are no transforms in the scene, there is no point running this   script
            if not transformInScene:
                  raise RuntimeError, 'There are no transforms in the scene!'
            badAttrs = list()
            # Loop through each transform
            for thisTransform in transformInScene:
                  if thisTransform not in ['front','persp','side','top']:
                  allAttrs = cmds.listAttr(thisTransform, keyable=True, scalar=True)
                  allAttrs = [ i for i in allAttrs if i = "visibility" ]
                   print allAttrs     
                   for attr in myList:
                       if attr in allAttrs:
                           currentVal = cmds.getAttr( thisTransform + "." + attr )
                           newVal = currentVal * percentage
                           cmds.setAttr(thisTransform + "." + attr, newval)
                           print "Changed %s. %s from %s to %s" % (thisTransform,attr,currentVal,newVal)
                       else:
                           badAttrs.append(attr)

            if badAttrs:
                print "These attributes $s are not valid" % str()

        myList = ["translateX", "translateY", "translateZ", "scaleX"]
        changeXtransformVal(myList, percentage=1.0)
```

This is part of a school project and after fixing the indent, I cant seem to find the problem

Answer (score 2):

The line above...

```
               cmds.xform(sphere1, t = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

is missing a closing parentheses for the `xform` call.

Comment: You found that in a cursory look? Dayyum, you're good. And here I was looking only at the first time that method was called :P

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Mostly just a matter of tracing backwards from the line indicated in the error. The indicated line clearly doesn't have a syntax error, so the next potential culprit is the previous line. After a while you get an eye for matching parens.

Comment: @Amber I just usually just put the whole thing into my IDE and let it do my work for me! :P But thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one ')' at the line "cmds.xform(sphere1, t = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)"

look you use two '(' but only one ')'

just add one at the end:

replace cmds.xform(sphere1, t = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) 
with 
        cmds.xform(sphere1, t = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))